# Array in payload is string, need to coerce to array type (DataWeave)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a payload I'm receiving from debezium/kafka as
`"reasons": "[7,10,9]"` with the array as a string.

I need to filter the array to extract when the item is 10 or 11. Since the array is actually a string in the payload I need to coerce it to an array to filter.

This is my current solution, but I feel there has to be a more efficient way:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = payload.payload.after
var reasons = data.reasons replace "[" with "" replace "]" with "" splitBy  "," filter ((num, numIndex) -> num != "10" and num != "11")
---
{
"dnsType": if (dnsType[0] == "11") "clinical" else if (dnsType[0] == "10") "non-clinical" else ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string content is compatible with a JSON array then you can use the read() function to let DataWeave parse it for you.

Example `read(data.reasons,"application/json")`

Comment: Thanks! Would it make sense to parse the entire payload to JSON? Would the same method work?

Comment: No, `read` needs a string. It won't if the input is a JSON itself.

Comment: If the input is a JSON DataWeave already parsed it and it is a DataWeave object in memory. That's the reason that you can access its keys (for example payload.after). On the other hand if the input is a string containing a valid supported format (JSON, XML, etc) then you can use read().